# 'NoneType' object is not iterable to SQLAlchemy session.commit()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I want to add sight to my postgres db, but on commit such error throws:

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnK4Q.png)

Class where i call add and commit (self.session.add(sight) works fine):

```
class SightsRepository:
def __init__(self, role):
    self.role = role
    session_manager = SessionManager()
    session_manager.setRole(role)
    self.session = session_manager.getSession()

def __del__(self):
    self.session.close()

def findSightByName(self, name):
    return self.session.query(Sights).filter(Sights.name == name).first()

def findSightById(self, id):
    return self.session.query(Sights).filter(Sights.id == id).first()

def findAllSights(self):
    return self.session.query(Sights).all()

def addSight(self, sight):
    print(self.session)
    self.session.add(sight)
    self.session.commit()
```

my session manager where i get session from:

```
class SessionManager():

admin_engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:1@localhost/Excursions")
unlogged_engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://unlogged_user:unlogged_user@localhost/Excursions")
logged_engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://logged_user:logged_user@localhost/Excursions")
guide_engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://guide:guide@localhost/Excursions")

def __init__(self, role=0):
    self.role = role
    self.sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=self.unlogged_engine)
    self.session = self.sessionmaker()

def setRole(self, role):
    if 0 <= role <= 3:
        self.role = role
    else:
        raise Exception("Wrong role")

def getSession(self):
    if self.role == 0:
        self.sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=self.unlogged_engine)
        self.session = self.sessionmaker()
        return self.session
    elif self.role == 1:
        self.sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=self.logged_engine)
        self.session = self.sessionmaker()
        return self.session
    elif self.role == 2:
        self.sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=self.guide_engine)
        self.session = self.sessionmaker()
        return self.session
    elif self.role == 3:
        self.sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=self.admin_engine)
        self.session = self.sessionmaker()
        return self.session
    else:
        raise Exception("Wrong role")
```

All is done by postgres connection.
Also trying to add to another model works fine without any errors (working code below):

```
class GuidesRepository:
def __init__(self, role):
    self.role = role
    session_manager = SessionManager()
    session_manager.setRole(role)
    self.session = session_manager.getSession()

def __del__(self):
    self.session.close()

def findGuideByFIO(self, name, surname, patronymic):
    return self.session.query(Guides).filter(Guides.first_name == name).filter(Guides.last_name == surname)\
        .filter(Guides.patronymic == patronymic).first()

def addGuide(self, guide):
    self.session.add(guide)
    self.session.commit()

def findGuideById(self, id):
    return self.session.query(Guides).filter(Guides.id == id).first()

def getAllGuides(self):
    return self.session.query(Guides).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just dropped the database and initted all again and all started working.